# Activity Indicator is not showing in front of view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a view in Which I have added a UIScrollview. In UIScrollView I added an UIImageView. After Picking Image from ImagePicker I am adding image to UIImageView.

**Problem :** I am showing UIActivityIndicatorView before adding image to ImageView.

Case 1: When I add activity Indicator to self.view It is showing behind the UIScrollView means not showing at all.

Case 2: If I add Indicator to Scrollview it is not adding in view.

I tried many thing **bringSubviewToFront , insertSubview:indicator aboveSubview:myscrollview**

Here is my **CODE :**

```
  scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, Screen_width, Screen_height - 60)];
scroller.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:scroller];
scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(Screen_width, 667);


profileImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, Screen_width-40, Screen_width-40)];
profileImageView.backgroundColor = gray;
profileImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
profileImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
profileImageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;


-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{

_profileIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
_profileIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(40.0, 20.0, 60.0, 60.0);
_profileIndicator.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:_profileIndicator];
[_profileIndicator startAnimating];




}
```

Comment: Have you tried showing it on main thread? Try viewDebugging to get the root cause.

Comment: you are adding UIActivityIndicatorView into your view but your code in picker delegate check your picker delegate.so this will present a new view controller.It wont show your indicator

Comment: Indicator is adding on View but below scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

All the UI things should be in main thread. So, please make sure you are using UIActivityIndicator in main thread.